# Northern Brewer or Midwest Supplies kits?

Tags: kits

My intent is not to start an emotional series of responses, but rather to understand the general feelings about recipe kits from Northern Brewer and Midwest. Personally, I have had good luck with Northern Brewer kits in the past, but, in some cases, Midwest has styles that I would like to try that I can't get from Norther Brewer. I'm interested in hearing about the differences between the two from brewers who have a good deal of experience with both suppliers.

Comment: Down vote with no explanation? Seems like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: I did not downvote, but its sort of an opinion based base question, it should probably be a wiki.

Comment: Not sure when the merger happened but their online operations are now the same - operated by Midwest iirc. So the choice probably comes down to the physical kit rather than service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't speak to Midwest, but I know NB has some good recipe kits because I developed them for them.  I can personally vouch for those.

Answer (score 1):

For them both located in MN, I used to order only from Midwest, took almost a week to get my order in Indiana. Nothern Brewer was here in 2 day...That's my VOTE

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Northern but have heard good things. 
Midwest is great. The have good kits and great service. I am a newbie and they have been very helpful. I have called them a few times with a question, and they did not not hesitate to answer. They also accidentally sent the wrong yeast, I emailed them and they sent the correct one to me with no questions asked. I would reccomend them... but you would probably be fine with both!

Answer (score 0):

I've had great luck with NB's kits - specifically the Paterbier (a wonderful little beer), the Caribou Slobber (brown), the petite saison and the Innkeeper (British bitter).

Answer (score 0):

I've only used midwest, which were high quality, but why not try both?  I'm sure Northern has just as good kits.  Buy a kit from each, brew and compare.

Worst case is you'll have 2 good beers.  Best case is you'll answer your question posted here.